# In if statement how to tell the different between JSX.Element and plain object?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

For data in `subMenuData` i have a simple `object`:

```
  {
    id: 9,
    name: 'Test1',
    subMenuData: [{ name: 'First Link', children: [{ name: 'SubLink', url: '' }] }],
  },
```

But sometimes i will have an object that will have a React component

```
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Test2',
    subMenuData: <TestComp />,
  },
```

So in my type i have

```
  subMenuData: JSX.Element | { name: string; children: { name: string; url: string }[] }[]
```

So both of them is an object but is there a way to tell the difference when doing if statement? In this particular statement i want the `Test1` to be rendered but if i pass `Test2` then i will have a different if statement for that to be rendered.

```
        {typeof menuData.subMenuData === 'object' && (
          <div>
            {menuData.subMenuData.map((item, idx) => {
              return <div key={idx}>{item.name}</div>
            })}
          </div>
        )}
```

Right now it's trowing me this error and this is because is trying to render Test 1 that is a simple object as `Element` type object

```
Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Element | { name: string; children: { name: string; url: string; }[]; }[]'.
  Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Element'.ts(2339)
```

Comment: you could use `Array.isArray(subMenuData)` as only one of the types is an array

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) (or [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) if you only care about arrays) if you have a class that can match that object or as a workaround for the missing `map` function/attribute simply check if it's not `undefined`:

```js
if (menuData.subMenuData.map) {
    // do stuff with map()
}
```

Example:

```js
if (menuData.subMenuData instanceof Array)
if (menuData.subMenuData instanceof YourClass)
```

```js
        {menuData.subMenuData.map && (
          <div>
            {menuData.subMenuData.map((item, idx) => {
              return <div key={idx}>{item.name}</div>
            })}
          </div>
        )}
```

Comment: it did but i've used the one that was suggested from thedude